# How could you get a following button to display "Follow <@username>" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I wanted the "follow button" to display, "Follow + username" (with username being an instance variable for each different user), what would be a good way to accomplish this?

```
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow, <%= @user.name %>" %></div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *string interpolation*, which replaces a variable with its value.

`<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow #{@user.name}" %></div>`

Useful link: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Follow, #{@user.name}" %></div>
```

This is normal string interpolation in Ruby. If you are into using I18n, you could do this:

```
<div class="actions"><%= f.submit t(:follow, :name => @user.name) %></div>
```

And in your locales en.yml:

```
en:
  follow: "Follow, %{name}"
```

/ Carsten